# Modify list of objects via WebService, how to get final Value List?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I get data from a web service, I need to send this data to another service to modify some values, so when I get the data there are more async calls to make. I don't know how to get the final values.

What I want to call:

```
SomeService.getSomething(id).then(function(something) {
    SomeOtherService.addXToDatas(something.data).then(function(fixedData) {
        $scope.data = fixedData;
    });
});
```

What I have:

```
    someOtherService.addXToDatas = function(datas) {
        datas.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
            getSomethingFromApi(value.something).then(function(bla) {
                array[index] = bla;
            });

        });
    }

    someOtherService.addXToData = function(data) {
            getSomethingFromApi(data.something).success(function(response) {
                order.someMore = response.data;
            });
        }           
    }
```

Unfortunately I have no actual clue how to accomplish this in javascript. 
For a single object I could use a callback, but for a list of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular.js has build-in implementation of Q, so you could use promise combination `Q.all`. It takes array of promises and returns a promise that is fulfilled when all other promises are.

You can easily create array of promises with Your code using `.map` instead of `.forEach`:

```
someOtherService.addXToDatas = function(datas) {
    return $q.all( datas.map(function(value, index, array) {
            return getSomethingFromApi(value.something).then(function(bla) {
                array[index] = bla;
            });

        })).then(function() {
            return datas;
        });
}

SomeOtherService.addXToDatas(something.data).then(function(fixedData) {
    $scope.data = fixedData;
});
```

## Explanation:

1. `datas.map()` creates an array of promises. API calls themselves will be executed asynchronously.
2. `$q.all()` returns a promise which is fulfilled when all promises passed to it from (1) are fulfilled.
3. Final `then` returns modified `data` array. It is called after all promises from (1) are fulfilled and all modifications of `data` are made.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want an array filled with data from the async calls in `addXToDatas`, you can do that like this:

```
someOtherService.addXToDatas = function(datas) {
    var promises = [];

    datas.forEach(function(value, index, array) {
        promises.push(
            getSomethingFromApi(value.something)
        );
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

And in your controller:

```
someOtherService.addXToDatas([data1, data2,data3])
    .then(function(resultArray) {
        console.log(resultArray);
    });
```

`$q.all(promises)` will return an array (in order) with the values of the promises. More info about `$q` and `$q.all` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all).

Comment: I dont know if I get it correctly... I have data coming from  webservice1, I need to send this data to another service (via addXToDatas) this function will add some data to the existing objects from webservice1. WebService1 Results -> Service1 -> WebService2 Results -> Scope. Am I missing something?

Comment: In your example both functions are in `someOtherService`, but they're actually in 2 different services ?

Comment: Oh, sorry for the confusion. addXToDatas is just a wrapper for addXToData. What I dont understand is, how do I finally add the data from the second calls to the "previously get data". Sorry. :/